# What is the alternative for secretsmanager.AttachmentTargetType in new version @aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager: 1.20.0?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

with version 1.19.0 , below script works fine.

```
  import secretsmanager = require('@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager');
  const target : secretsmanager.ISecretAttachmentTarget = {
            asSecretAttachmentTarget: () => ({
                targetId: `arn:aws:rds:${this.region}:${this.account}:cluster:${this.database.ref}`,
                targetType: secretsmanager.AttachmentTargetType.CLUSTER
            })
        };

   const myUserSecretAttached = this.dbSecrets.addTargetAttachment('AttachedSecret', {target})
```

with version 1.20.0, addTargetAttachment is deprecated.So I have used attach. In ISecretAttachmentTarget targetType ' secretsmanager.AttachmentTargetType' is deprecated. so what is the alternative ?
I have tried the below script which throws error 'Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative.'

```
 import secretsmanager = require('@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager');
  const target : secretsmanager.ISecretAttachmentTarget = {
            asSecretAttachmentTarget: () => ({
                targetId: `arn:aws:rds:${this.region}:${this.account}:cluster:${this.database.ref}`,
                targetType: secretsmanager.AttachmentTargetType.CLUSTER
            })
        };

   const myUserSecretAttached = this.dbSecrets.attach(target)
```

Answer (score 0):

`AttachmenTargetType` has been wrongly deprecated.

Only some of its constants are deprecated: `secretsmanager.AttachmentTargetType.CLUSTER` is now `secretsmanager.AttachmentTargetType.RDS_DB_CLUSTER` and `secretsmanager.AttachmentTargetType.INSTANCE` is now `secretsmanager.AttachmentTargetType.RDS_DB_INSTANCE`.

Note that if in your example `this.database` is a `Cluster` instance, you can simply do:

```ts
this.dbSecrets.attach(this.database);
```

Comment: hi @jogold , `this.dbSecrets.attach(this.database)` throws error 'Argument of type CfnDBCluster is not assignable to parameter of type ISecretAttachmentTarget'.

Comment: I said if `this.cluster` is a `Cluster` instance not a `CfnCluster` instance. Also, this has been merged https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/5950

Comment: @jogold applicable for serverless redshift?

Comment: @Impermanence there's currently no CDK construct for redshift serverless